# use variable from jquery method in a angularJs controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to get $scope.selectedIndicator outside the methode on change to use it in the angular controller.

Any ideas on how I could get $scope.name ? Comments on the above fiddle are also welcome.

```
$scope.setSelectedIndicator = function () {
            $('#indicatorSelect').on('change', function(){
                $scope.selectedIndicator=$('#indicatorSelect').chosen().val();
                var res = $scope.selectedIndicator.split("|");
                $scope.selectedIndicatorId=res[0];
                $scope.selectedIndicatorName=res[1];
                console.log($scope.selectedIndicatorName);

                });
            $scope.name = $scope.selectedIndicatorName ;
        };
        $scope.setSelectedIndicator();
```

Comment: so what you try do: set `$scope.name` on change event, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you can just use angular's `ng-change` directive for this purpose. It's better to avoid jQuery inside angular and also just for getting the chosen value from `indicatorSelect`, jQuery is not required. You can do it via angular.element itself.

Anyways, Inside your jQuery `change` event handler, you must use `$scope.$apply()` to make the change in `selectedIndicatorName` reflect in `$scope.name`.

As you're outside of angular context, you need to run `$scope.$apply()` for the change to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is intended for use with angularJS. You will have to use `jQuery` instead of `$`. Here is your new function:

```
        jQuery('#indicatorSelect').on('change', function(){
            $scope.selectedIndicator = jQuery('#indicatorSelect').chosen().val();
            var res = $scope.selectedIndicator.split("|");
            $scope.selectedIndicatorId=res[0];
            $scope.selectedIndicatorName=res[1];
            console.log($scope.selectedIndicatorName);

            });
```

Comment: $ is used in all angularjs services like $http, $filter, $q, etc.. Other than that `$` is not assigned to any function by angular. But it's better to use jQuery to avoid conflicts though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.setSelectedIndicator = function () {
            $scope.selectedIndicatorName='';
            jQuery('#indicatorSelect').on('change', function(){
                $scope.selectedIndicator = jQuery('#indicatorSelect').chosen().val();
                var res = $scope.selectedIndicator.split("|");
                $scope.Id=res[0];
                $scope.Name=res[1];
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.selectedIndicatorName = $scope.Name;
                });
                console.log($scope.selectedIndicatorName);

            });
```